# Visual Studio 2022 features unnavailable due to internal error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

From the last about half an hour I have been getting these errors:

```
StreamJsonRpc.ConnectionLostException : The JSON-RPC connection with the remote party was lost before the request could complete. ---> System.OperationCanceledException : The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at async StreamJsonRpc.MessageHandlerBase.WriteAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.TransmitAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.InvokeCoreAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at async StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.InvokeCoreAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.InvokeCoreAsync[TResult](<Unknown Parameters>)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.BrokeredServiceConnection`1.TryInvokeAsync[TService,TResult](<Unknown Parameters>)
```

Here is also a screenshot:[image]

Currently I am using VS Community 2022 17.0.5. These errors display when I am writing code or when it is building. There are no errors in building the application and it runs. But any type of IntelliSense fails, also the code doesn't automatically align. I have tried reloading and re-installing but these errors persist.

Comment: Try turning off the "Intellicode" suggestions.

Comment: Still the same issue.

Comment: Im also getting this issue, constantly...did you get a resolution @AchoVasilev?

Comment: @RichardDeeming that's not really a solution.  What's the point of using Visual Studio if one needs to turn off any connected features?

Comment: @Mark That's why I posted a comment rather than an answer. Unfortunately, this isn't something anyone outside of Microsoft can fix, so there's no way anyone can post an actual solution that doesn't involve turning off the affected features.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue last time and I am able to turn it off by uncheck "Enable IntelliTrace"
[Sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJKD7.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I was facing this issue with VS 2022(.NET 6) project I closed and reopen Visual Studio and it's worked for me

Comment: @phuzi how is this a "thanks" answer?